# Lucene optional exact match query syntax

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I want to search a lucene index specifying search criteria for a number of fields.
All fields are exact matches except for "title" and "content". A search term **must** appear in either or both of these fields

I've tried variations on the following but must be missing something as my results aren't coming back as expected. Any help appreciated.

(+make:dell +model:lattitude +year:2010) +title:p0175 **OR** +content:p0175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+make:dell +model:latitude +year:2010 +(title:p0175 content:p0175)`

Documents with p0175 in both fields will rank higher than those matching only one field.